# Selection of only existing combination before the normalization operation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to normalize some variable just only if existing combinations in `var1`and `var2` using `for`, in my example:

```
# Create my variables
var1<-c(rep(6,25),rep(7,5))
var2<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,5,5,5,5,5)
var3<-rnorm(30)

# Create a data frame
mydf<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
str(mydf)

# Inspection by var1 and var2
table(mydf$var1,mydf$var2)
#  1 2 5 10 11
#6 5 5 5  5  5
#7 0 0 5  0  0

# I'd like not considering "0" combinations!!

# My idea is create a subset just only for combinations that have values, but if I make:

var1ID <- unique(mydf$var1)
var2ID <- unique(mydf$var2)

for(a in 1:length(var1ID)){

for(b in 1:length(var2ID)){

mydf_sub <- mydf[mydf$var1 == var1ID[a] & mydf$var2 ==var2ID[b],]
print(var1ID[a])
print(var2ID[b])

# Normalize function
normalizevar <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    return((x- min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
print(normalizevar(mydf_sub$var3))
}}

# [1] 6
# [1] 1
# [1] 0.0000000 0.1235632 0.1541684 1.0000000 0.3910381
# [1] 6
# [1] 2
# [1] 0.7911505 0.0000000 0.6296866 1.0000000 0.1904835
# [1] 6
# [1] 5
# [1] 0.6571259 1.0000000 0.1402675 0.0000000 0.4068031
# [1] 6
# [1] 10
# [1] 0.7060784 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.4842629 0.9560127
# [1] 6
# [1] 11
# [1] 0.4096362 0.4831099 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.5492811
# [1] 7
# [1] 1
# numeric(0)
# [1] 7
# [1] 2
# numeric(0)
# [1] 7
# [1] 5
# [1] 0.6208451 0.3219927 1.0000000 0.4012007 0.0000000
# [1] 7
# [1] 10
# numeric(0)
# [1] 7
# [1] 11
# numeric(0)
```

Here a have a problem because I'd just only the output with values existent combinations and not `numeric(0)`. Please, any help with my problem or any `dplyr` approach to solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the question, the normalizing function was not removing `NA`'s, if any.

```
# define the function at the beginning of the script,
# never in a loop
normalizevar <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  (x- min(x, na.rm = na.rm))/(max(x, na.rm = na.rm)-min(x, na.rm = na.rm))
}

# make the results reproducible
set.seed(2021)
# Create my variables
var1 <- c(rep(6,25),rep(7,5))
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,5,5,5,5,5)
var3 <- rnorm(30)
mydf <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
```

### Base R solution

There is no need for nested loops, two (unnested) `*apply` loops will do it. And in just 3 code lines.

```
# create the groups of var1, var2
sp <- split(mydf, mydf[1:2])
# keep the sub-data.frames with more than zero rows
sp <- sp[sapply(sp, nrow) > 0]
# and normalize var3
lapply(sp, function(X) normalizevar(X$var3))
```

---

### `dplyr` solution

A `dplyr` solution could be the following.

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(var1, var2) %>%
  mutate(new_var3 = normalizevar(var3))
```